# Conocer si un dispositivo USB esta siendo utilizado en windows con C#

Tags: c#, windows

estoy intentando crear un programa que permita saber si un dispositivo USB "X" esta siendo utilizado independientemente del tipo. Adjunto el link y parte del código que utilizo para obtener el listado de dispositivos.

**Código:**

```
public class Usb
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// obtiene las usb de la computadora
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<USBInfo> GetUSBDevices()
        {

            //creamos una lista de USBInfo
            List<USBInfo> lstDispositivos = new List<USBInfo>();

            //creamos un ManagementObjectCollection para obtener nuestros dispositivos
            ManagementObjectCollection collection;

            //utilizando la WMI clase Win32_USBHub obtenemos todos los dispositivos USB
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
               (@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))

                //asignamos los dispositivos a nuestra coleccion
                collection = searcher.Get();

            //recorremos la colección
            foreach (var device in collection)
            {
                //asignamos el dispositivo a nuestra lista
                lstDispositivos.Add(new USBInfo(
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
                ));
            }

            //liberamos el objeto collection
            collection.Dispose();
            //regresamos la lista
            return lstDispositivos;
        }
```

[Código completo](http://hdeleon.net/como-obtener-los-dispositivos-usb-en-c/)

Comment: A que te refieres con "estar en uso"? cuando está "un raton en uso" por ejemplo?

Comment: Hola,  te doy unos ejemplos: mouse que se mueva o presionen un boton

Comment: Te complemento con mas ejemplos:  --mouse mover o presionen botón /--Teclado presionar cualquier tecla /-- PenDrive trasferir o borrar archivo /--scaner enviar imagen a PC.

Comment: Me temo que eso no es sencillo. Si siempre va a ser un raton lo que gestiones,puedes utilizar global hooks. Pero dudo que haya una funcion que de esa informacion indéendientemente del tipo de dispositivo...

Comment: ¿Exactamente que dispositivos quiere escuchar? porque cada dispositivo de hardware tiene sus propios eventos, y cada componente de hardware se comporta distinto, asi la pregunta estaria muy ambigua

Comment: La idea era encontrar algo genérico que se pueda implementar con cualquier dispositivo USB y que pueda ser configurado cambiando el ""DeviceID"" u otro parámetro del dispositivo seleccionado.